# curl returns "Failure when receiving data from the peer"

Tags: php, curl, command-line-interface

I'm retrieving data from an URL using curl.

Everything works fine if the php code is called via a HTTP request or if the URL is entered in Firefox. If the very same code is executed from a PHP CLI script curl_exec returns false. The error message is "Failure when receiving data from the peer".

Any ideas why curl is not working?

When I set the curl output to verbose I get:

```
Setting curl to verbose gives:
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Last-Modified: Mon, 01 Aug 2011 13:04:59 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
< Cache-Control: pre-check=0
< Cache-Control: post-check=0
< Cache-Control: max-age=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< Content-Type: text/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2011 13:04:58 GMT
< 
*   Trying 153.46.254.70... * Closing connection #0
* Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

This is the Code:

```
// if curl is not installed we trigger an alert, and exit the function
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
    watchdog('sixtk_api', 'curl is not installed, api call cannot be executed',array(),WATCHDOG_ALERT);
    return $this;
}
// OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
$ch = curl_init();

// Set URL to download
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->request);

// Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Timeout in seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 180);


// Download the given URL, and return output
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$output) {
    $error = curl_error($ch);
  echo($error);
}

// Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: The code you've been given is incomplete. Please reduce it to the minimum needed to show you case: Remove `$this` dependencies and instead of the `watchdog` function call, just `die()`. Otherwise folks here are not able to reproduce your problem. The URL in question is missing as well.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot post the URL since I have to keep this confidential (that's not my decision!).

Comment: After all, I think there's a difference between calling curl from cli and via a web server?

Comment: Both can have their own configuration. For example the user-agent might differ, but that's speculation. CLI might be blocked from security related applications like firewall or things like SELinux. So it can depend on a lot of things. What you can actually do is to sniff the network traffic and take a look which point is preventing to send or recieve data.

Answer (score 0):

try wget . if that fails too but you can access the address from another IP/device , this probably means your IP is being blocked or filtered out by either firewall/nginx anti ddos attack . try proxy .